# DRF: a way to use default UserProfile field in serializer?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Using current User model in your serializers is easy:

```
user = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        read_only=True,
        default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault()
    )
```

but what if I have my own `UserProfile` model and I want to use current `UserProfile` in a serializer.

Just doing `CurrentUserDefault().profile` does not work, of course because at this point this is an empty object.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out this problem is very easily solved. If you look at the source code of CurrentUserDefault class, you will see it is very simple:

```
class CurrentUserDefault(object):
    def set_context(self, serializer_field):
        self.user = serializer_field.context['request'].user

    def __call__(self):
        return self.user

    def __repr__(self):
        return unicode_to_repr('%s()' % self.__class__.__name__)
```

I guess `set_context` is called by `Serializer`, and then `__call__` method called to recieve the object.
So it is very simple to rewrite this code in any way you want.

**TLDR**

Just add this somewhere:

```
class CurrentUserProfileDefault(serializers.CurrentUserDefault):
    def __call__(self):
        return self.user.userprofile
```

And where ever you need your profile just write:

```
user_profile = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        read_only=True,
        default=serializers.CurrentUserProfileDefault()
    )
```